# Django model field that's actually a reference to a field in a related model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Apologies in advance if this question is hard to follow – I'm not sure how to phrase it. Basically, I'm trying to create a sort of "pseudo-field" in a Django model that works exactly like any other Django field except that it's actually a reference to a field on a related model.

As an example, suppose I am running a hotel for dogs. In my hotel, I have rooms, and each room is assigned to a customer and contains a dog.

```
class Customer(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)

class Dog(Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    customer = model.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # The dog's owner

class Room(Model):
    customer = model.ForeignKey(Owner, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    dog = model.ForeignKey(Dog, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

The corresponding tables in the database look something like this

```
CUSTOMER:

| ID | NAME       |
___________________
| 01 | John Smith |
| 02 | Jane Doe   |


DOG:

| ID | NAME  | CUSTOMER_ID |
____________________________
| 01 | Rover |     01      |
| 02 | Fido  |     01      |
| 03 | Spot  |     02      |


ROOM:

| ID | DOG_ID | CUSTOMER_ID |
_____________________________
| 01 |   01   |      01     |
| 02 |   03   |      02     |
```

So, my boss notices that we're storing redundant data in the DB: the rooms table doesn't really need to have its own customer ID column: the customer is always the resident dog's owner, and each room contains only one dog, and each dog has one owner, so we can always get the customer assigned to the room by going to the dog table and looking up the owner. I've been asked to remove the customer ID column from the rooms table in a way that is "totally transparent" to the rest of the code base.

To start with, I can convert `customer` into a `@property` in the Room class, with a custom getter:

```
class Room(Model):
    dog = model.ForeignKey(Dog, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    @property
    def customer(self):
        return self.dog.customer
```

So now everywhere in the code where we do something like `c = room.customer`, it continues to work. The problem is, the code base is full of Django field queries like `room__customer`, which all stop working when I make `customer` into a `@property` of `Room`. I could change them all to `room__dog__customer`, which works fine, but then the change wouldn't be "totally transparent".

I did some research and I've tried implementing a custom manager and annotating the query set for Rooms:

```
class RoomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().annotate(customer=F('dog__customer'))
```

When I do that, I can use `room__customer` in queries, but not `room__customer__name`, I suppose because `F()` is returning the primary key value rather than a model instance (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#using-f-with-annotations).

So my question is, is there a way to make this work that I just don't know about? A way to make it so that Room acts like it has a direct foreign key relationship with Customer, without having `customer_id` stored in the rooms table?

Comment: Apologies I know this isn't an answer to the question. But I want to comment on how 'transparent' should be interpreted. when coders use shorthand like room__customer, they expect certain behavior. If you're overriding framework methods in a way that isn't predictable, well that's risky. It would be very difficult to debug any issues down the line if it's unclear how framework methods are behaving. It's also weird that storage efficiency is what's being prioritised here. They queries are going to be slower without a FK reference. And the business logic is not obvious at all after the change.

Comment: Basically this: "I could change them all to room__dog__customer, which works fine, but then the change wouldn't be "totally transparent"." Is the best solve. This way the code reflects what's actually happening in the DB.

Comment: I believe that "totally transparent" means "make a change in one place and have all of the rest of the code keep functioning without needing to change 400 different source files." This is my first real task at a job I started last week, so I'm a bit hesitant to go back to my boss and say that this is a bad idea and that we shouldn't be doing it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing your manager's line about "totally transparent" is simply a way to say "whatever you change shouldn't screw up other business logic." In other words, the application should continue to work as it does today. I doubt very much that he cares how many files you edit (though, he could be a micro-manager, in which case ... I'm sorry).

That said, I think your solution of changing `room__customer` to `room__dog__customer` is the best course of action. The change makes it obvious to other Django developers what's going on (you're walking the relationship), and it's a fairly straightforward change. Yes, you may end up having to touch a number of files, but such is life when you muck around with the backend schema.

One thing you need to consider with this change, however, is potential performance implications. You may need to introduce `select_related` calls to your queries, to ensure that tables are joined properly. Otherwise, doing the `room -> dog -> customer` lookups may become expensive (with an extra database round trip *per lookup*; this really adds up in a loop).

Best of luck!